# Freeze excel editing while vba is running

Tags: excel, vba, locking, freeze, editing

I have an excel sheet that I want to edit via vba script, but I need the users to not be able to edit any cells or click any buttons while the script is running. Due to a programs that I Shell after the excel button click, editing is enabled during this VBA sub run. What I need is a way to programmaticaly lock all cells for editing except by VBA. How can I do this?

Psuedo_Code:

```
Shell _ "PROGRAM1"
Shell _ "PROGRAM2"
Dim shellobject As PROGRAM2
shellobject.Connect "PROGRAM1"
shellobject.dothings
if(shellobject.success) then
Cells(1,1).Value = "HUZZAH!"
Else
Cells(1,1).Value = "OH NO MR BILL!"
End If
shellobject.dootherthings

etc.....
```

Comment: not sure what exactly your script or where it is running from, but usually you cannot edit a spreadsheet while VBA is running. The only way to stop the script is `Ctrl+Break`.

Comment: I can edit while this is running. It runs on button click, shells two programs, and proceeds to edit cells based on responses received from the two shelled programs.

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds very unusual - under normal circumstances you cannot edit Excel during the execution of a macro. Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @PeterAlbert I'm unable to post the relevant code, but I do believe that the ability to edit during run is due to the programs I am shelling. What I need is a programmatic way to lock all cells for editing except by VBA.

Comment: so you're automating Excel from the (Power)shell or via a normal VBA macro contained in Excel? *confused*

Comment: @PeterAlbert I'm automating Excel via a normal VBA sub attached to an excel form button. That button then uses the "Shell" command to shell two other programs (terminal based record systems and an api program that can communicate with the terminal). Those programs feed data to the excel sheet.

Comment: Can you show the UserForm as Modal`? This should prevent any data entry in the cells. And for the buttons on the form, set `.Enable = False` while you're waiting for the external feed.

Comment: @PeterAlbert How would I go about showing the user form as modal? I'm going to try the button enabling bit in a few minutes to see if that portion works. Also, I've added some psuedo-code above to help clear things up a bit.

Comment: if you look at the properties of the UserForm in the VB Editor, there is a `ShowModal` property. If it is set to `TRUE`, you cannot select the underlying Excel until it is closed.

Comment: @PeterAlbert I'm uncertain as to the UserForm. My buttons are just inserted directly into an excel sheet. I access the buttons directly. I haven't dealt a great dealt with excel form items beofre, so this area is a bit new to me.

Comment: see my answer below for detailed instructions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using a UserForm, set it to be *modal* in the Properties dialog of the form (press <kbd>F4</kbd> in case it is not visible):

[image]

This way, the user cannot click in Excel outside the form unless it is closed.

Also, you can try to disable the buttons during the execution. This code should do that:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    SetButtonsEnabled False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Your code here

    SetButtonsEnabled
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub SetButtonsEnabled(Optional blnEnable As Boolean = True)
    Dim btn As Control
    For Each btn In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf btn Is CommandButton Then btn.Enabled = blnEnable
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I do not have a UserForm in my properties window, only a "Sheet1 Worksheet". The buttons are inserted directly into the excel sheet. I don't believe they have a userform container, but are used as seperate entities.

Comment: Alright, so I created a small modal form that appears when the button in the excel sheet is clicked (simple go and cancel buttons, nothing fancy). That succesfully locked up everything, and setting the enabled property of the buttons kept those from being pressed. Thanks for sticking with me on this one.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considering disabling input from the keyboard. This could be a brute force way of accomplishing what you need but it's a thought.

You can use

```
Application.DataEntryMode =
```

to disable input from the keyboard. Set it to off once your script starts and turn it back on right before your script ends.

Again, this could be considered brute force but just an idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Would also add `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` while we're brute forcing things.

Comment: This does not work. I've added Application.DataEntryMode= xlOff to the beginning and Application.DataEntryMode = xlOn to the end, and editing is still enabled during the run of my vba sub.

Comment: hmm... From reading your comments above, I'm assuming your sub routine looks something similar to this...

`Sub ExecuteShell
     Shell( <location of shell command> )
End Sub`

If this is the case, the Application.DataEntryMode may not work as I originally intended. We may need to find a different method for stopping input because the VBA will have finished before the shell command has. Can you confirm that the above code is how your shell is being executed. Can you show some of the shell command?

Comment: @even-steven I've added some psuedo-code above to clear things up a bit. There is a dll whose objects handle communication with the shelled program. That shelled programmed communicates with the second shelled program via what I can only assume is a simple socket connection with the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Following worked for me:

Use `Application.Interactive = False` at the beginning and re-enable it at the end. This will disable user clicks/entry attempts until the Macro/Userform/any code part completes its operation.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to comment to Steventnorris and Even-Steven but I am not able to, so just putting an answer here.

```
Application.DataEntryMode= xlOff in the beginning should be set to
Application.DataEntryMode= xlOn 
and then at the end of the code
put in  
Application.DataEntryMode= xlOff
```

I just tried this and it has stopped me from editing the sheet so in case anyone else is trying.