# Prevent a command button from being clicked multiple times while a sub is iterating

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an Excel macro that will run when a command button is pressed (VBA 7.1), and will not allow the user to click multiple times during execution, however every trick I've found online to this end has not worked: even while locked, disabled, and with focus on a different object, the user can still cause the sub to run multiple times before the first one finishes.

My current code looks like this (`run_slow_macro` opens a Word document to make changes, then saves it, and can take about 30 seconds to complete.)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If CommandButton1.Enabled = False Then
        MsgBox ("STOP CLICKING")
    End If

    Me.Frame1.SetFocus
    CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    CommandButton1.Locked = True
    CommandButton1.Caption = "WAIT"

    Call run_slow_macro

    CommandButton1.Caption = "CommandButton1"
    CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    CommandButton1.Locked = False


End Sub
```

When I click the button, it locks and becomes disabled, and the caption changes as expected.  However, subsequent clicks do not cause the "STOP CLICKING" messagebox to appear, yet still cause the Word document to be opened multiple times, edited, and then closed.

The command button does not become unlocked/enabled until *after* all executions are completed, and the "STOP CLICKING" messagebox never appears.

I'm very confused as to how it's executing "Call run_slow_macro" each time, but seems to be skipping everything before and after that line once the first execution is in progress.

I have very little experience with VBA, and have been unable to find any solutions online (the above code is the culmination of the most common recommendation's I've seen), so I appreciate any advice that can be offered.

Answer (score 1):

This should disable the macro execution until it finishes. Read the code comments.

See that I'm using the variable defined as `HasStarted` in the `run_slow_macro` to tell the command button that it should exit while the macro hasn't finished.

```
Option Explicit

' This variable should be declared at the top of the module
Private HasStarted As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If HasStarted = True Then Exit Sub

    Me.Frame1.SetFocus
    CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    CommandButton1.Locked = True
    CommandButton1.Caption = "WAIT"

    Call run_slow_macro

    CommandButton1.Caption = "CommandButton1"
    CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    CommandButton1.Locked = False

End Sub

Public Sub run_slow_macro()

    HasStarted = True

    ' Do something

    HasStarted = False

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.  The only part I couldn't implement was "Option Explicit", since it would necessitate re-writing parts of the module that are outside my scope.  I also tried replacing the "then exit sub" with a message box, but this behaved identically to the "STOP CLICKING!" message box in the question, and never pops up at all.

Comment: You have to place the content of the `run_slow_macro` where the `' Do something` is located. did you do that?

Comment: I put the "HasStarted" boolean toggle at the start and end of the run_slow_macro sub, as you have it above.

I also tried making the button not visible (in addition to disabling and locking), and it *still* queues up clicks even when I can't see it.

Comment: Is this running inside a UserForm?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following.  I believe it has your answer.

[Freeze excel editing while vba is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903882/freeze-excel-editing-while-vba-is-running)